# testing normality for a two way anova, residuals as well as each sample?

Tags: anova, residuals, normality-assumption

to test a two way ANOVA do you have to test each sample for normality as well as normality for the residuals?

Comment: Consider the advice at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless . The answer by Harvey Motulsky would be particularly relevant to your question.